# Numbering the Chapter / Section / Subsection and the equation in align environment

Tags: sectioning, align, numbering

I am writing a notes for a subject (I am using `documentclass{report}`). In my project, I follow the layout of Chapter - Section - Subsection. I want to number the title of chapter, section and subsection in the form like

```
Chapter 1. ABC
1.1. ABC
 1.1.1. ABC.
 1.1.2. ABC.
1.2. ABC
 1.2.1. ABC.
```

So I implemented these code

```
% for chapter
\usepackage{sectsty}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\newlength\mylength
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\large{\hspace{0.04cm}}}
\settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

% for section
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}

% for subsection
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\hspace{-.55cm} }
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
```

However, when I use the align environment, the label of equation just goes like (1..1). I want my label of equation to follow a pattern like this

```
Chapter 1.
 Section 1.1.
   Equation (1.1)
   Equation (1.2)
  Subsection 1.1.1.
    Equation (1.1.1)
    Equation (1.1.2)
  Subsection 1.1.2.
    Equation (1.1.3)
    Equation (1.1.4)
 Section 1.2.
   Equation (1.3)
   Equation (1.4)
  Subsection 1.2.
    Equation (1.2.1)
    Equation (1.2.2)
```

How can I make it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `..` in the equation number because you include a dot in `\thechapter`. To remove it, redefine `\theequation` as you did for `\thesection` or `\thesubsection`:

```tex
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
```

Your equation numbering scheme seems a bit weird, since you reinitialize the equation counter in the first `\subsection`, continue in the next, but get back  in the next `\section`, this time to continue the first numbering.

You need to save the counter value used for sections, at the first subsection. Create a new counter for that

```tex
\newcounter{PreviousSectionEquation}[chapter]
```

and add a hook to `\subsections`:

```tex
\AddToHook{cmd/subsection/before}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection} = 0\relax% first subsection
    \setcounter{PreviousSectionEquation}{\value{equation}}%
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \fi%
  \renewcommand*{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
}
```

This will, at the first subsection, save the equation counter before its reinitialization. It also sets `\theequation` accordingly.

Add another hook to `\section` to pick back the value of `PreviousSectionEquation`,  if set, and reset `\theequation`:

```tex
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{%
  \ifnum\value{PreviousSectionEquation} > 0\relax%
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{PreviousSectionEquation}}%
    \setcounter{PreviousSectionEquation}{0}%
  \fi
  \renewcommand*{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
}
```

Full code (without unnecessary non compiling stuff):

```tex
\documentclass{report}

% for chapter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}

% for section
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

% for subsection
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\hspace{-.55cm} }

%% special equation numbering
\newcounter{PreviousSectionEquation}[chapter]

\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{%
  \ifnum\value{PreviousSectionEquation} > 0\relax%
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{PreviousSectionEquation}}%
    \setcounter{PreviousSectionEquation}{0}%
  \fi
  \renewcommand*{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
}

\AddToHook{cmd/subsection/before}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection} = 0\relax% first subsection
    \setcounter{PreviousSectionEquation}{\value{equation}}%
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \fi%
  \renewcommand*{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Chapter}

 \section{Section 1.1.}
   \begin{equation} Equation~(1.1) \end{equation}
   \begin{equation} Equation~(1.2) \end{equation}
  \subsection{Subsection 1.1.1.}
    \begin{equation} Equation~(1.1.1) \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} Equation~(1.1.2) \end{equation}
  \subsection{Subsection 1.1.2.}
    \begin{equation} Equation~(1.1.3) \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} Equation~(1.1.4) \end{equation}
 \section{Section 1.2.}
   \begin{equation} Equation~(1.3) \end{equation}
   \begin{equation} Equation~(1.4) \end{equation}
  \subsection{Subsection 1.2.}
    \begin{equation} Equation~(1.2.1) \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} Equation~(1.2.2) \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: weird equation numbering scheme]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful.

Comment: Btw, I also want to adjust the size of `\section` to `LARGE`, so I use ```\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}```
Is it fine ?

Comment: @PermQi You can customize the different section commands as you want. As long as you use `\section` and `\subsection` the hooks will be called and the code should work.